# `dart create` returns "Error when reading 'create': No such file or directory"

Tags: dart, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a `dart` CLI program (I frequently create `flutter` apps without issue).

I'm following [this tutorial](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/get-started) and the first step (after installing dart) is

```
dart create -t console-full cli
```

however when I do that I get the following error

> Error: Error when reading 'create': No such file or directory

---

I've tried reinstalling dart and that worked just fine, but didn't fix the issue.

---

I've also tried doing just

```
dart create example
```

And I get the exact same error (**Error: Error when reading 'create': No such file or directory**)

Has anyone else gotten this?
What is the fix for it?

Comment: What does running `dart --version` print?  I suspect that you are (perhaps inadvertently) running an old version of `dart`.  If you're using Linux or macOS, running `which dart` will tell you which binary you're running.

Comment: `Dart VM version: 2.7.1 (Thu Jan 23 13:02:26 2020 +0100) on "macos_x64"`

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/dart`

Comment: You were right @jamesdlin !

I just did a `brew upgrade dart` and now `dart create test` works !!

If you would like to put "upgrade dart using `brew upgrade dart`" as an answer I'll mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments from @jamesdlin for this answer.

This happens with an older version of dart.

Update to the latest dart to fix it.

```
brew upgrade dart
```